# plotting multiple dataframes in a single list on 3d plots python

Tags: python, pandas

This list of `dataframes` that i want to plot (3D plot) where one **axis** should contain the number of each `dataframe` in *list* i.e just the index **2nd axis** and **3rd axis** should contain certain columns from those dataframes in the list.

Code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
file_list = [f for f in listdir("Rohdaten_zeitreihen/") if isfile(join("Rohdaten_zeitreihen/", f))]


crystal_list = []
for file_name in file_list[:]:
    crystal = pd.read_csv(os.path.join("Rohdaten_zeitreihen/",file_name), sep="\s", skiprows=[1], engine="python")
    print(crystal)
    crystal_list.append(crystal)
#print("fin")
import numpy as np
#list1 = list(list1)
for j in range(len(crystal_list)):
    
    ind = crystal_list[j]
    tal = crystal_list[j]['time']
    ial = crystal_list[j]['IR']

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 15.8, 12.6
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(ind,tal,ial, c=ial, cmap='plasma', linewidth=1)
ax.set_xlabel("list")
ax.set_ylabel("time")
ax.set_zlabel("IR")
```

I am not getting what I trying to achieve, this just consisting the plots of just the single `dataframe` in the entire list, any helps?

Answer (score 0):

ok I have solved it myself had to just put few changes to the for loop and running the `plot` on the for loop

I am keeping the question open for future use

```py
for idx,crystal in enumerate(crystal_list):
    tal = crystal['time']
    ial = crystal['IR']
    ax.scatter(idx,tal,ial, c=ial, cmap='plasma', linewidth=1)
```